# How to export variable when the system starting

Tags: linux

When I use remote mode to login my server to execute my GUI program. I need to set `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INSIRECT=yes`.  How can I just set once. Don't set it each time when I login my server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  export command into .bashrc file in your home directory or into rc.local file or into /etc/profile file based on your convenient.

export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INSIRECT=yes

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what language your "GUI program" is written in, but you need to add the equivalent of the following C incantation at the top of your main method:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
setenv ("LIBGL_ALWAYS_INSIRECT", "yes", 1);
// your code here
```

Comment: Yes, I use c language. Can I set it outside? BTY, which C standard version startes to support this function. I remembered that it only support `getenv` before.

Comment: @Samuel setenv has been in the C library since Version 7 AT&T UNIX, which was before I was born.

Comment: ,@hd1 Is it a C standard function or be supported by system. I think it is a C standard function. Because it's in `stdlib.h` header file. But I only can find `fesetenv` in c99 standard.